# Azure Function Service Bus Queue Trigger - "A host error has occurred. System.Private.Uri: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString."

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have created an Azure Function (V2, .NETCore) for Service Bus Queue Trigger. But I am getting below error while running the project.Please find below the screenshots.

[local.settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfNxS.jpg)

[Error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xazH.jpg)

[Error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlfA1.jpg)

My Function Code is given below.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionTriggers
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please check if you have provided the right service bus connecting string? Regarding how to get it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal#get-the-connection-string

Comment: @JimXu : I have added the correct connection string in local.settings.json

Comment: Could you please provide your local.settings.json?

Comment: @JimXu: I have updated question with screenshots of local.settings.json and one more error for reference.

Comment: According to the picture you provide, the value of ```ServiceBusConnString``` is also the storage account connection string. Please use service bus connection string. It should be like ```Endpoint=sb://<your service bus name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<your share key>```. Regarding how to get it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal#get-the-connection-string

Comment: @JimXu : Thanks Jim Xu. That solved my problem.

Comment: it is useful for you, could you please [accespt the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more persons who have similar issue.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue even after providing the right values for ServiceBusConnString. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Azure function service bus trigger, we must provide the Service Bus ConnString. The connection string should be like `Endpoint=sb://<your service bus name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<your share key>`. Regarding how to get it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal#get-the-connection-string.